# $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a principal ideal domain with $\alpha^3=\alpha+7$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, ideal-class-group

I'm trying to solve exercise 20 of chapter 5 of the book Number Fields by Marcus.
$$ \text{Prove that $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a principal ideal domain when $\alpha^3 = \alpha+ 7$} $$
I just solved the exercises 15 to 19 of the same chapter using Minkowski's bound and studying the factorization of $2R$ and $3R$.
This time when I apply Minkowsi's bound i get that $||J|| \le 10.27$ and I have to study the factorization of $2R,3R,5R$ and $7R$.
I know that $\operatorname{disc}(\alpha)=\operatorname{disc}(R)=-1319$ that is a prime number so I know that $2R,3R,5R$ and $7R$ are unramified because they do not divide the discriminant but I can't say anything else.
In the book is contained the hint that $7 = \alpha^3- \alpha$ but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What is $\Bbb A$?

Comment: SInce $7=\alpha^3-\alpha=\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha-1)$ it looks likely that $(\alpha)$, $(\alpha+1)$ and $(\alpha-1)$ are the prime ideal factors of $(7)$. I'd check that; if so they are all principal, and I could delete $7$ from my list.

Comment: Not 100 percent sure but for $p \leq 5$, the equation $x^3-x=7$ has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$. So $(2),(3),(5)$ should remain prime ideals...

Comment: @Bernard $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of all the algebraic integers on $\mathbb{Z}$ so writing $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]

Comment: Thanks @AnginaSeng, I'll try immediatly to follow this idea